# polarization of symplectic manifold

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, sg.symplectic-geometry, geometric-quantization

The [geometric quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_quantization#Geometric_quantization) can be considered as an approach the formalize the way of
associating a quantum theory corresponding to a given classical theory.
Suppose we start with a sympetic manifold $(M,w)$ with symplectic form
$w$. The  geometric quantization procedure falls into the following
three steps: prequantization, polarization, and metaplectic correction.
The polarization is a choice a
Lagrangian subspace of the complexified tangent bundle
$TM \otimes \mathbb{C} \to M$. Therefore it's a kind of choice of a
distiguished subbundle $P \subset TM \otimes \mathbb{C}$. The quantum
is then defined as space of sections $s: M \to P$.

Now from physical viewpoint the term Polarization suggest that the
polarization procedure makes something geometrical, but up to now
I haven't any idea what idea hides behind the polarization. I only
accept is as a formal step in order to obtain a new associated object
with interesting properties, but purely abstractractly.

Does anybody know any didactically valuable example which probably
vizualize what is roughly going on there geometrically or a way how it should be recomended to
to think about the polarization
intuitively? Why calling this procedure polarization is a meaningful name? In [physicsStackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/591666/polarization-procedure-in-geometric-quantization?noredirect=1#comment1332524_591666) I asked some days ago an identical question. Following Adolfo Holguin's hint this terminology arise also seemingly independently from mathematical physics as an important concept in symplectic geometry without be immediately connected to ma phy and I would like to understand if there is an motivating reason why this procedure is called polarization.